# Hudson trigger builds remotely gives a forbidden 403 error

Tags: unix, continuous-integration, hudson, wget

I have a shell script on the same machine that hudson is deployed on and upon executing it, it calls wget on a hudson build trigger URL. Since its the same machine, I access it as http://localhost:8080/hudson/job/jobname/build?token=sometoken

Typically, this is supposed to trigger a build on the project. But I get a 403 forbidden when I do this. Anybody has any idea why? I have tried this using a browser and it triggers the build, but via the command line it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this because Hudson requires authenticated sessions to trigger remote builds?

Comment: My hudson webapp is protected. I am guessing its a security problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently if Hudson is protected using a security mechanism, you need to authenticate the build requests. See this wiki link for more details http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Authenticating+scripted+clients

Since I used the auth mechanism that was shipped with Hudson, calling the build scripts invovled. I used

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --http-user=user --http-password=password http://hudson.yourcompany.com/job/your_job/build?token=TOKEN
```

to run the build script.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that's what the token was for, to avoid having to put  passwords into scripts. :(

Comment: This is only when hudson itself is security enabled. If its inside the firewall, you dont need to enable Hudson security and can run this trigger without the password.

Comment: I also thought the whole purpose of this token passing is to skip authentication. But it is only works, if you grant _read_ access to the anonymous user...

Comment: Ancient thread, I know, but is there a way to get wget to shut up entirely?  I'm on Windows, and running this command line with the -q option still prints some stuff out.  I'm also adding "-O -" and "> NUL" (note the single L) to the line, and that shovels the resulting index.html down the bit black hole, but it all feels VERY hacky to me.

Comment: due to this url is broken, we can check this url: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/authenticating-scripted-clients/

Answer (score 0):

If you use matrix-based security, you can set Job Read and Job Build permission to Anonymous, so you don't need a user and password in your post-commit hook.

Another tip is to turn on polling without setting a date and use this URL:

http://hudson.yourcompany.com/job/your_job/**polling**?token=TOKEN

Your job will be build just if there were svn changes (no need to build when changing other projects, creating tags etc.)

Comment: Nooo, adding read permission to Anonymous is not a good idea IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same errors. In my case I had to add the Jenkins-Crumb header to the HttpPost object to make it work.

```
post.addHeader("Jenkins-Crumb","crumb value");
```

To find the crumb value for your Jenkins instance, install Firebug or any plugin n your browser which will help you see the request headers. Go to your job page at http://server_name:port/jenkins/job/job_name
Press F12 to activate Firebug, got to Net tab. Click Enable Auto - refresh link at top right of your page. Now every 5 seconds you should see an Ajax Request being made to fetch the buildHistory. In that request, examine the headers. There should be a header for Jenkins-Crumb, it can also be under name .crumb depending the Jenkins version you are using. You it in your Java code.